# adding :nth-child using jquery wrap function

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to display two column drop down menu in header of one of my eCommerce site. So to display the sub-products I am using `ul` listing which added dynamically on the conditions.

To display the sub products I am using ul:nth-child(n) and wrapping 4 `ul` using .wrap() jquery function which added on right side.

Please refer the attached screenshot.
[image]

MY main problem is when there is no sub-products; extra `ul` listing which is the part of description area are added automatically on class `.sub-menu-product` and display in menu area, which is the problem.

Here is the .wrap function.

```
$('h3:nth-child(7), ul:nth-child(n+7), h3:nth-child(9), ul:nth-child(n+9), h3:nth-child(11), ul:nth-child(n+11), h3:nth-child(13), ul:nth-child(n+13)').wrapAll('<div class="sub-menu-product" />');
```

Here is the Working **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vomomiqo/1/edit)**.

Comment: I'm not real sure what you are trying to do but I think your markup <ul><li> could be better. did you know that you can wrap an `ul` inside an `li` and then you can do lots with css only.. made here the easyest example http://jsfiddle.net/5Vnn9/

Comment: not excatly what I want. if you see the screenshot. There will be total 7 `UL`.  3 `UL` are on the left side and other 4 `UL` should be on right side. To count the rest 4 I am using `nth-child` and wrapping rest 4 `UL` using `.wrap()` function which will display on right side. but in one condition when 4 `UL` are not there.. other `ul` are added on menu section which i don't want.